# Set name to groupby size column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that I need to count the unique items of a certain row. In the example below, I want to label the name for the below function as "NUM_CIK". What's the best way to assign a name to the groupby column?

Current code:

```
    cik_groupby_cusip_occur = cik_groupby_cusip_occur.groupby(
        ['CUSIP'], sort=True)['CIK COMPANY'].size().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Sample Output:

```
CUSIP
594918104    4560
037833100    4457
023135106    4053
02079K305    3545
478160104    3472
```

*Wanted Output:*

```
CUSIP       NUM_CIK
594918104    4560
037833100    4457
023135106    4053
02079K305    3545
478160104    3472
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `name` parameter:

```
(cik_groupby_cusip_occur = cik_groupby_cusip_occur
         .groupby('CUSIP')['CIK COMPANY']
         .size()
         .sort_values(ascending=False)
         .reset_index(name='NUM_CIK'))
```

Or [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
cik_groupby_cusip_occur = (cik_groupby_cusip_occur['CUSIP']
            .value_counts()
            .rename_axis('CUSIP')
            .reset_index(name='NUM_CIK'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use `reset_index(name='NUM_CIK')`

Or:

```
cik_groupby_cusip_occur = (cik_groupby_cusip_occur
 .groupby(['CUSIP'], sort=True)['CIK COMPANY']
 .agg(NUM_CIK='size')
 .sort_values(by='NUM_CIK', ascending=False)
)
```